# Change row color on a ListView using JScript.net

Tags: listview, jscript.net

I'm trying to change the color of a row on a ListView with JScript.Net.
I'm scripting againts an application where I dont have access to the code, but I can add scripts that modify the ListView.

What I'm trying is this:

```
this.listView = controller.RenderEngine.ListControl.ListView;
this.listView.Items[0].UseItemStyleForSubItems = false;
this.listView.Items[0].SubItems[1].ForeColor = new System.Windows.Media.SolidColorBrush(Colors.Yellow);
```

or

```
this.rows = IList(listView.ItemsSource); // Use the ItemsSource to get data     
rows[1].Forecolor = new System.Windows.Media.SolidColorBrush(Colors.Yellow);

this.listView.Items(0).FonttWeight = System.Windows.Controls.FontWeights.UltraBold;
```

Anything of this is working.

I can make it work however with instructions like:

```
listViewItem = listView.ItemContainerGenerator.ContainerFromIndex(i);
listViewItem.Background = color;
```

But with this solution if there is scroll or change of focus on the ListView the changes on the painted rows disapear.

Any ideas?.

Thanks for your time.

Comment: Can you make raw JS calls? Preferably jQuery? Can you modify the style of the page?

Comment: I can add standart .net libraries, I can't use jQuery.

Comment: The application is written in in c# WPF.